# how changing openvpn default port on centos7

Tags: openvpn, centos7, firewalld, systemctl

I am trying to change Openvpn default port from 1194 to 8080

I change port 1194 to port 8080 on server.conf at server and change the client config file like that

```
remote 15.15.15.15 8080
```

then I restart openvpn but does not work.

I also use this code for opening the port 8080 on firewall d

CODE: SELECT ALL

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
```

but still connection doesn't work :( :( :( :(

but when i change the port to 1194 agine openvpn works agine good!!

**if otherwise the server.conf (port 1194) i had to change any option or file which thats not works or not??**
**please help me what can i do for to change default port?**

Comment: In your config file its 8080 port but in your firewall you wrote 8070.

Comment: Please be more specific about the `doesn't work` part. What's the exact error message you receive?

Comment: i used [firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8070/udp --permanent] for test 8070 port but thats not works too

Comment: doesn't work i mean when i change the port of server.conf to port 1194 and then restart openvpn and firewall thats works as well but when i change the port to another port there is no connection anymore!?